# SSRS Browser Not Rendering The Same As SSDT

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I have a very strange thing happening and I don't know how to resolve so looking to the experts to point me in the right direction please.

I am building a SSRS report to match our clients existing report (built using Crystal Reports). I have been given exact criteria to match such as font size, font, etc and sizes of the various controls. In one part of the report, I have 3 pie charts (uurgh!) next to each other. Each has a custom legend to display the series values and the percentage. Depending on the option at runtime, these legends can contain 9 or 10 items. I understand there is little that can be done in determining how many legend entries appear in each "column" of the wide table, if used, but what I am experiencing is doing my head in.

Below is what the pies currently render as in SSDT (VS 15.9.16)
[image: VS Render]

When I deploy to SSRS and view the report, using exactly the same data source and parameters, I get the following.
[image: SSRS Render]

You can see in the middle pie, its switched to a column even though the legend is set to wide table and is missing entries. The third pie is a wide table but has dropped Financials off the bottom of the legend.

And why, just out of interest, does the browser version show a space between the number and % sign but the SSDT version doesn't?

This is very frustrating as I expect the browser to return the same as VS. I've tried Edge, Chrome and IE, same every time. I have tried using Auto Table and Wide Table on the legend, makes no difference.

Any suggestions for ensuring the browser renders the report exactly the same as the dev environment would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I've seen kind of the same thing happen when legends get wrapped due to lack of space. Try making everything more spacious to start with. I usually set the font size 2 points larger than I need, make sure it's all shown and then reduce the font size back to what it should be. Also, make sure that the fonts are installed on the server as it may be substituting them for some that looks the same.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the response. I am really limited on space as this report has to fit on A4 portrait. The font is Arial so is installed on the server.

Comment: I understand, it was just to see if that resolved it and then you would at least know what you were fighting, then you can start with simple things like reducing the padding on everything. Remember that each renderer will output slightly differently too. If you export to pdf for example it might be fine.

Comment: I'll give it a try. When exported to PDF, which is the final output, it looks the same as the browser. I wasn't aware of padding on legends, if there is it would be useful